# Several significant cross correlations at various lags and with different signs?

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation, lags

I have a cross correlation plot here: [image]

I’m familiar with interpreting one obvious value at a given lag. For example, consider the positive correlation between x and y at lag -1 in the chart. This means “an above average value of x is likely to lead to an above average value in y one period later.” This is because lag = -1 is correlating x at time t-1 and y and time t.

But what if we have several significant correlations with varying signs, as I do in this chart? Do we say we have several relationships? Would it be appropriate to say that “sometimes an above average change in x leads to an above average change y one period later AND sometimes an above average change in x leads to an above average change in y two periods later, and so on for all significantly negative lags?” In general, is it fair to say all these relationships exist between the two series such that there’s inconsistency in what typically happens when x is above average?

I am only interested in the negative lags.

Comment: If you wish to modify your original question, just edit it.  Please review our [help] for more guidance on how this site works.

Comment: Forgot about that! Edited my original. Would you please help me? I’m crying in my car at a Taco Bell.